# How to cast a non-generic delegate to a generic delegate

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I would like to create an instance of [ValueGetter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.runtime.data.valuegetter-1?view=ml-dotnet) that has the following signature:

```
public delegate void ValueGetter<TValue>(ref TValue value);
```

The instance should throw an exception if `TValue` is not of type `int`, and set `value` to `myInt` otherwise.

The best I could come up with is:

```
public void GetVal<TValue>(ref TValue val)
{
    if (typeof(TValue) != typeof(int))
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    val = (TValue)(object)myInt;
}
```

However this is not ideal, as it involves boxing. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why is boxing a problem?

Comment: @DStanley Performance. Microsoft wrote this strange delegate for performance reasons, as can be seen in the link, which is why it doesn't simply return `TValue`.

Comment: Do you have a _measurable_ performance problem? I don't see the link addresses performance - only _efficiency_, which in this context I interpret as _easier to code_.

Comment: @DStanley It's definitely not easier to code, so it must mean performance!

Comment: By easier to code I mean versus an alternative way. How would you get the value _without_ the delegate?

Comment: @DStanley they could have made a simpler delegate: `public delegate T ValueGetter<T>()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure that the code *actually* boxes the value. It would only box if you stored the value in an `object` variable, which you do not do. You just cast it twice, which might be optimized away in reality.

Secondly, it's not clear why that would be a *problem*.

Thirdly, throwing an exception seems odd. Under what circumstances would something other then `int` be used? Is an exception the appropriate response in those cases?

Comment: 1) I just benchmarked it, calling the method using generics and without, and they take the same time, so it seems that you are correct that there is no boxing.
2) It is common knowledge that boxing is bad.
3) You are right, I just added the exception to make the method look complete.

Comment: Actually see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.runtime.data.irow.getgetter?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_Runtime_Data_IRow_GetGetter__1_System_Int32_), that it should throw if `TValue` is of the wrong type.